# Grammar to recognize postfix formulas

Tags: grammar, compiler-theory, language-theory

I'm trying to create a *postfix to infix* converter, and I'm unable to create the grammar for postfix formulas. I've been also looking for it for a while without success..

**What grammar could I use to recognize valid postfix expressions?**

The tokens I need are: `number`, `+`, `*` and `^` (*pow*).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest

```
E ::= number | E E + | E E * | E E ^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it also recognizes expressions that leave more than one value in the stack. Like: `1 2 3 +`. :(

Comment: @Oscar Mederos: No, `1 2 3 +` is not regognized. The grammar requires that you have for each operator EXACT two parameters, and a parameter can either be another (sub-)expression or a number.

Answer (score 0):

Valid in what sense? Resulting in one value?

```
B ::= number | B B O
O ::= + | * | ^
```

Comment: This allows also expression like  `5 +` which is no valid postfix formula (as you need 2 on parameters for the add).

Comment: There was no definition of what valid meant, but I think I understand now.

Comment: Nevermind, your solution is identical and earlier than my edit.